# Should the HTTP request header content-length match the difference in the range of bytes requested?

Tags: http

The below shows a request and response header for a range of bytes in a video file. The response header shows the 'content-length' being 25,000, although the range of bytes requested is actually 50,000. Why Shouldn't the content-length specify the number of bytes of the message body and therefore in this case the difference in the range boundary bytes of the video file?

```
Request

GET /videos/sample.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.re
Range: bytes=25000-75000

Response

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 25000
Content-Range: bytes 25000-75000/100000

<50,000 bytes of video data will follow>
```